# Error with Cisco VPN client driver

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

When I try to connect from Cisco AnyConnect I get the following error message.

> The VPN client driver encountered an error. Please restart your computer or device, then try again

---

> AnyConnect was not able to establish a connection to the specified secure gateway. Please try connecting again.

When I tried to google this , I found this [The VPN client driver has encountered an error](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100597-technote-anyconnect-00.html#anc37). But it (changing registry values) did not help.

It said to disable `Routing and RRAS` but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem went away after I uninstalled and re-installed Cisco AnyConnect...

Answer (score -3):

1. CLick start then type in run
2. Run box opens, type in C:\$WINSRC
3. Box opens up>> click on AnyConnectRepair
4. CMD box opens, wait until says press anykey...
5. Retry your VPN connection should work now.
6. You are welcome.